# Blade: How to include default view If include view error?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to `@include('item_1')`, if not the `item_1` view then `@include('default')`.

Idk how to include `default` view.

My laravel version is 5.2.

Comment: Why would you do this? You can check in your controller what view needs to be returned right?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`exists()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#basic-usage) method:

```
@include(View::exists('item_1') ? 'item_1' : 'default')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (View::exists('item_1'))
   @include('item_1')
@else
   @include('default')
```

Just use a if statement